# "It is+......+ing" VS "It is+...... +to infinitive"

Tags: grammar

1) It is nice to play here "knowing" I have done well in the
past. (this sentence is collected from a newspaper)

2) It is nice to play here "to know" I have done well in the
past.

I am always confused choosing the option of (ing) or( infinitive) after "It is " and "there is and there are " and I have found nothing about those in my research.  Is there any rule for those?  Please help me out.

Comment: Even after all this time, the example is too strange. It’s not impossible, but it is highly unlikely that any newspaper ever printed that passage with "knowing" quotated like that.

It remains a shame you posted no research, and still ’It is nice to play here "knowing" I have done well in the past’ is grammatically fine but semantically, mostly pointless.

Could you take the option of (ing) or( infinitive) after "It is " and "there is and there are " somewhere like English Language Learners, please?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is slightly ambiguous.

> It is nice to play here knowing I have done well in the past.

Other answerers and commenters seem to be interpreting the "knowing" phrase as modifying the entire clause "It is nice to play here", thereby making it a dangling modifier whose implicit subject (the speaker) does not play a role in that clause. Dangling modifiers are not a grammatical error, but they often require extra effort for readers to understand (even when the intended subject seems obvious to the writer).

An alternative interpretation is that the "knowing" phrase is modifying the infinitive phrase "to play here", in which case its implicit subject is the same as the implicit subject of the infinitive. I think this interpretation is actually more likely, and if I'm right, there's no dangling modifier. (But since dangling modifiers aren't actually an error, this is of mostly theoretical interest.)

Either way, the "knowing" phrase is an adverbial, meaning roughly "while knowing […]" or "because of knowing […]".

There is no one general rule that will tell you when to use a participle and when to use an infinitive, but this construction — an adverbial adjunct describing the context — is specific to participles, never infinitives.

> It is nice to play here to know I have done well in the past.

This is theoretically grammatical with a certain meaning, but the meaning is so strange that the result is almost gibberish. To elucidate the grammar, here's a more-realistic sentence with the same structure:

> It is important to play here to show you can still do well.

The "to show" phrase describes a *purpose*; it could also be written as "in order to show […]". The word "important" helps prime this interpretation, since it's very common to specify a purpose for which something is important; but that is a matter of semantics rather than grammar, and infinitives of purpose can be used almost anywhere that the meaning works (except where there would be ambiguity due to another available interpretation for the infinitive, in such case an explicit "in order to" may be needed).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence sounds correct and is commonly used.

You can rewrite them as:

1. Knowing I have done well in the past, it is nice to play here.
2. To know I have done well in the past, it is nice to play here.

The first sounds better. The second sounds odd. I think this is more about usage/semantic than grammar.

Comment: How can your first sentence be correct?  It looks like a "dangling " participle, doesn't it? If I am mistaken, then which rule did you so as to make those sentences?

Comment: The part "Knowing I have done well in the past" is an adjunct and it answers the question "Why?".

Comment: Actually, no, you can’t. “Knowing I have done well in the past, it is nice to play here” does work grammatically even though its meaning is cloudy. However, “To know I have done well in the past, it is nice to play here” is a text-book case of nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

**Neither** construction is grammaticality correct, and neither clearly says what you want to say.

Given  the proper fixes, however, you could use either the participle "knowing" or the infinitive "to know" in a correct sentence.

#### Sentence 1

> 1) It is nice to play here, ***knowing*** I have done well in the past.

In its current position, the [participial phrase](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm) "knowing I have done well in the past" is a dangling participle. These phrases have to act as adjectives in the sentence, modifying the nearest noun in the rest of the sentence.

But you definitely aren't asserting that "here" knows you have done well iin the past -- a place can't do that. Sometimes you can cheat if the nearest noun can't possibly be modified by the participle, and there is another one that can.

But in your case, the only other noun in the sentence is the [impersonal pronoun](https://www.grammarbank.com/impersonal-pronouns.html) "it". "It" can't know you have done well in the past. There's no other candidate.

So then, ask yourself "who or what knows you have done well in the past?" And the answer would be ***"I do!***". Because of that, you have to use "**I**" as the antecedent of the "knowing" phrase.

There's another problem, however. *knowing I have done well in the past* doesn't give a good reason why *it is nice to play here*.  You're emphasizing that it's nice to play **here** and not somewhere else. Doing well in the past, perhaps in several other places, says nothing about that. You can correct that by explicitly saying you have done well **here**.

So you could say

> Knowing that I have done well here in the past, it's nice **for me** to play here.

But  wait...you're the one saying it. That means you are implicitly telling people you know this, and "knowing" is superfluous. You can use "knowing", but an actual conjunction such as "because" is better.

> It's nice to play here, **because** I have done well here in the past.

You can even omit the linkage; the semicolon is a wondrous object:

> It's nice to play here; I have done well here in the past.

#### Sentence 2

> 2) It is nice to play here "to know" I have done well in the past.

This is also incorrect. The infinitive phrase *to know I have done well in the past* has to play the part of a noun in the sentence. But there's no noun role left for it.

However, the fact that you are **playing** can probably be inferred from context. So if you're willing to change what is "nice" from "playing"to "knowing", you can correctly say

> *It's nice **to know** I have played well here in the past*.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/combining-sentences-with-participle-phrase-and-conjunction

Comment: Spencer, that's not right. "It is nice to play here, knowing I have done well in the past" has no grammatical problem; it merely lacks clear meaning.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I originally thought that, and started writing my answer saying just that. But as I developed the answer, the more I realized the sentence's problems went back to that dangling participle. OP's intended meaning can be deciphered easily enough.

Comment: @Spncer I think not. TimLymington's alternative does show how the grammar still works despite the context. Only the *meaning* is odd.

You're right about 2), though. that's simply wrong…

Comment: _Dangling participle_ is one of those concepts which were invented only to make people wrong. In most cases it is perfectly clear what is meant, and the claim that it is grammatically wrong belies a concept of English grammar which is inadequate, in that it fails to capture what English speakers actually say.

Answer (score -3):

Please be very careful about what you take from newspapers.

Even though it is grammatically acceptable, ‘It is nice to play here "knowing" I have done well in the past’ has almost no semantic meaning.

Grammatically, that is no different from ‘It is nice to sit there "knowing" I have been green in the past.’

Semantically, is the difference obvious?

‘It is nice to play here "to know" I have done well in the past’ as you wrote it, will not work without extra punctuation.

‘It is nice to play here, "to know" I have done well in the past’ almost works.

‘It is nice to play here; "to know" I have done well in the past’ does work.

As to your confusion choosing the option of (ing) or (infinitive) after "It is" and "there is and there are" could you rephrase that, with clear examples, please?

Comment: It is nice to login to StackExchange knowing that I can answer most of the questions on the front page. Do you consider that sentence meaningless (as opposed to smug or mistaken)? If not, you might like to rephrase this answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim and while it would be very easy to change your wording without changing your meaning, if you think there's a meaningful comparison there, you might like to rephrase dz420's examples…